# Quickbooks WebConnect Customer ExternalId

Tags: synchronization, quickbooks

I have a customer whose original QB Company file got corrupted. They created a new company and must've somehow imported their customers from the old company file. It seems that the QB IDs of all the customers are now different. Since my system syncs data over to QB, I've got all of my customers mapped from our internal Guid that identifies them to the QB ID we got back when we first added those users. But now the mappings are all invalid. I've deleted all the mappings to have the customers get synced over again but that isn't working either because the CustomerQueryRq doesn't support querying by ExternalGuid and sometimes the customer has changed their name on our end so querying by Full Name doesn't turn up any results. Then when I attempt to add the customer, I get a failure because QB claims the ExternalGuid is already in use. Can anyone suggest anything I could do to be able to ask QB for its users?

Even just a way to dump all of the QB Customers in such a way that I could get at their ExternalGuid and QBID columns is all I really need to recreate the mappings in my own database?

***EDIT***
I have managed to export the users from Quickbooks.
File->Utilities->Export->Lists to IIF Files
Then I selected "Customer List" and chose OK

This generated a .iif file which is basically a tab delimited file with some extra (unnecessary) cruft at the top. I removed the cruft with my favorite text editor, renamed the file to a .txt and was able to open it with Excel successfully.
There were some of the customer fields there - unfortunately they didn't export the ExternalGuid which I truly need to complete the mapping to my system but they did at least sort of export the QBID.
By "sort of" I mean they exported two columns that could be manipulated together to produce the QBID. The columns are *REFNUM* and *TIMESTAMP*. If you convert the *REFNUM* to a hex number and pad it out to 8 digits with a leading 8 and then 0s followed by a hypen (**-**) followed by the *TIMESTAMP* column you'll get the QBID. Here's my Excel formula:
`=CONCATENATE("8", REPT("0", 7-LEN(DEC2HEX(C2))), DEC2HEX(C2),"-",D2)`
where column C was the *REFNUM* and column D was the *TIMESTAMP*
For example if the *REFNUM* was **20591** and the *TIMESTAMP* was **1354913279** then you'd convert the **20591** to hex and get **506F**. Pad that out to 8 digits long with a leading 8 and 3 zeros to get **8000506F** and tack on a hyphen and the timestamp for a final QBID result of **8000506F-1354913279**

I still don't have a great solution since there's plenty of duplicated names in my system so I can't definitively look up all the users without getting that ExternalGuid out of them so I'm still hoping for someone who knows how to do that. But at least this might help someone who needs to get the QBID out of the QB system.

Answer (score 0):

After I managed to do the Customer Export in QB (see above), I then had a list of all the QB Customers and with the manipulation described above I was able to create the QBIDs of all the customers. I hacked together a test version of my existing Quickbooks Web Connect web service and had it send over XML like in the **sendRequestXML** web method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerQueryRq>
      <ListID>80000034-1194125010</ListID>
    </CustomerQueryRq>
    <CustomerQueryRq>
      <ListID>80000067-1205524684</ListID>
    </CustomerQueryRq>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Each time the QB Web Connect called my **sendRequestXML** web method I'd ask for another 100 users by their QBIDs.
I also hacked the **receiveResponseXML** web method to parse the XML that came back.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRs>
    <CustomerQueryRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
      <CustomerRet>
        <ListID>80000034-1194125010</ListID>
        <TimeCreated>2015-11-10T06:31:17-05:00</TimeCreated>
        <TimeModified>2015-11-10T06:31:17-05:00</TimeModified>
        <EditSequence>1447155077</EditSequence>
        *****************************************
        ***Intentionally Omitted Customer Data***
        *****************************************
        <ExternalGUID>{0c75ac09-61a1-400e-a8e7-4d8c50e9f267}</ExternalGUID>
      </CustomerRet>
    </CustomerQueryRs>
    <CustomerQueryRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
      <CustomerRet>
        <ListID>80000067-1205524684</ListID>
      ...
      ...  
      </CustomerRet>
    </CustomerQueryRs>
  </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Not all returned customers had an ExternalGuid in it because some customers had been manually instead of being added through our QBWC interface. If the returned customer did have an ExternalGuid, I'd log that to a database. In the end it took a few hours to run through the 60K+ customers but I was able to get the ExternalGuid from each item in QB that had one.

I hope this helps someone else who may be experiencing the same issue. Also QB should export all of their fields, not just what they think people want.